# Vuetify : v-data-table header \n(new line)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue.js(2.6.11) with Vuetify(2.4.0).

And the code below is my abbreviated code.

```js
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
          hide-default-footer
          class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
          
=============================================================   
data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      pageCount: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      headers: [
        { text: 'Calories\n(per 100g)', align: 'center', sortable: false, value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Protein\n(per 100g)', align: 'center', sortable: false, value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Carbohydrates\n(per 100g)', align: 'center', sortable: false, value: 'carbohydrates' },
      ],
      items: [],
    };
  },
```

I wrote \n(new line) in every header, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: what about '`Calories <br> (per 100g)`' and don't forget to change ' to `

Comment: Hi @firefly , I tried it but didn't work. it looks like below in the header 

`Calories<br>(per 100g)`

Comment: i didn't use vuetify though but there should be a <template #header>  option for the headers. I mean you should manually iterate the headers and directly write the text for each header.

Answer (score 0):

The point is `\n` will shows like white space if not in `<pre>` tag,
So you can only use the slot

```html
<v-data-table
  headers="headers"
  items="items"
  items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:header.calories="{ header }">
    Calories<br>new line
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

`v-slot:header.calories` **calories** is one of your headers field